# How to show only the contact form on a Uservoice widget?

Tags: uservoice

I'm using the Uservoice JS widget API to display only the contact form, but it always reverts to showing the 'Post an idea' (smartvote) form. Here's what I've configured:

```
UserVoice.push(['set', {
  accent_color: '#000000',
  trigger_color: 'white',
  trigger_background_color: '#c9000b',
  contact_enabled: true,
  smartvote_enabled: false,
  post_suggestion_enabled: false
}]);

// Add default trigger to the bottom-right corner of the window:
UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', {
  trigger_position: 'top-right',
  trigger_style: 'tab',
  mode: 'contact'
}]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Running into this too, did you fix it finally ?

Comment: @koma let's see... i believe you have to buy a paid plan to do what i was trying.